# Was this scene in "The Last Jedi" an homage to "Hardware Wars"?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

The scene in The Last Jedi where Finn and Rose

> Steal First Order uniforms

Opens with a steam iron descending down from the sky as if it was a spaceship.

Is this an homage to [Hardware Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_Wars) which opens with a steam iron being chased through space by a toaster?

Image from Hardware Wars:

[image]

<sup>Image take by me from random [Hardware Wars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ymFxkFfIhU) video on Youtube</sup>

Image from Star Wars:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for reminding me of this and asking if it was intentional. One of several delightful moments in the movie.

Comment: I never knew of Hardware Wars but found that scene amusing anyway. For a moment i thought that space ship looks like a steam iron and then realized that the scene was in fact not depicting a space ship.

Comment: I was thinking Space Balls myself, but you're correct, Hardware Wars. Thanks for the connection!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes. Johnson’s openly stated so [in an interview](http://uproxx.com/movies/star-wars-the-last-jedi-hardware-wars-rian-johnson/):

> Literally the first question I asked Johnson in an interview on Friday was, **“That had to be a Hardware Wars reference in The Last Jedi, right?” Johnson let out a bellowing laugh and said, “I’m so happy you saw that.”** After explaining that I haven’t found too many people yet who have gotten the reference, Johnson said, “I know. Patton Oswalt, after he saw it, he DMed me just, ‘Hardware Wars!’ I was like, ‘Yes!’ It’s people of a certain age who will get that, I think.”

Comment: I saw the connection immediately .. but didn't know if it was deliberate or not.

Comment: Very fun. I'll have to check out *Hardware Wars*. I thought it was a play on Mega Maid from *Spaceballs* when I saw *The Last Jedi*.